# Move object while user holding touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, 2d-games

I want to create simple app (clone of Road Fighter actually http://youtu.be/CDMcY3wLd1Q) where: rectangle UIView (car) moves left, if user press left side of screen and it moves right if user press right side.

I already figured out how to recognise touches (two ways: with "UILongPressGestureRecognizer" and with "touchesBegan:" function) but i don't understand how to create animation.

Pseudocode should looks like this (or maybe i'm wrong):

```
if user touch
    if touch.coordinate.x>160 then
        while holding
            UIView.coordinate.x += 0.01;
    if touch.coordinate.x<160 then
        while holding
            UIView.coordinate.x -= 0.01;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another function called `-(void)touchesEnded` so when touchbegan, you keep move the car to one direction and stop moving while touchesended was called.
Simple solution is using a flag like `bool carismovingleft` call the loop moving function in touchbegin:

```
- (void)touchesBegan... {
    //mark the flag
    self.carismovingleft = true;
    //start moving the car  
    [self movingcar];
}

- (void)movingcar {
    if (self.carismovingleft) {
        //move the car subview to left a little bit
        .......
        //now we keep moving a little bit till someone  stop it
        //call moving again after a delay 
        //otherwise the car will move all the way in one frame
        [self performSelector: @selector(movingcar) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded... {
    //stop flag
    self.carismovingleft = false;
}
```

It's just a basic concept of how to implement it, you need coding by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So you want your object to start moving when the user touches and holds on a button, and keep moving until the user lets go?

A long press gesture recognizer gives you a delay before it gives you single press event. That won't work.

You need to implement touchesBegan/touchesEnded. Some variant of @highwing's approach should work. You'll need to fine-tune the delay intervals and the amount you move the car per interval.

Since you want both left and right movement, I'd probably use an enum to specify movement direction, and then use a switch statement in the movingCar method to handle movement in all the directions from one directions.

Following high wing's lead here, the code might look like this:

```
typedef enum 
{
  notMoving,
  movingLeft,
  movingRight
} movementDirections;

movementDirections currentDirection;

- (void)touchesBegan... 
{
  //mark the flag
  if (touchPoint.x > 160) 
  {
    currentDirection = movingRight;
  }
  else if (touchPoint.x < 160) 
  {
    currentDirection = movingLeft;
  }
  //start moving the car  
  [self movingCar];
}

- (void)movingCar 
{
  switch self.currentDirection 
  {
    case movingLeft:
      //move the car subview to left a little bit
      .......
      //now we keep moving a little bit till someone stop it
      //call moving again after a delay 
      //otherwise the car will move all the way in one frame
      [self performSelector: @selector(movingCar) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
      break;
    case movingRight:
      //move the car subview to right a little bit
      .......
      //now we keep moving a little bit till someone stop it
      //call moving again after a delay 
      //otherwise the car will move all the way in one frame
      [self performSelector: @selector(movingCar) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
      break;
    default:
      break;  //Do nothing (we're not moving.)
  }
}

- (void)touchesEnded... 
{
  //stop flag
  self.currentDirection = notMoving;
}
```

EDIT: I am a proponent of [**Allman style**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style) indentation (link). This is a valid alternative to K&R style indentation, which I despise. @evlogii, please do not change my code to use K&R style. This is a matter of personal taste. I won't convert your code from K&R style to Allman style, so you don't convert my code to K&R style, ok?